# test topic with gtest

Tags: ros, topic, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i wanna test a topic, what it actually publish, and when changing something, what the topic then publishes. My problem is, that i need to declare a callback function in the subscribe() member function of the nodeHandle.

What is the "best" way to handle that? I mean, in the main TEST() function a loop over a global variable till the callback has changed this global var, then end the main TEST() function?

i know ros.org/wiki/rostest/Nodes but its written in python, and i wanna write it in c++, perhaps someone knows a tutorial?

thanks
flo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58861/test-topic-with-gtest/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's effectively what you need.  You shouldn't need to do it in a global variable.  You can always use another container class and pass content that way.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0